# Python Select best 4 from a JSON list

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have a sorted JSON list, like this:

```
[{ "id": "1", "score": "5" },
{ "id": "1", "score": "4" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "9" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "8" },
{ "id": "3", "score": "99" }, 
{ "id": "3", "score": "98" }]
```

It is sorted by id, and base on id, the score is also sorted. Now I want select the best 4 scores of each id, and store them into a new list. The id may have more then 4 scores, also may not have more than 4 scores. The sorting time should be O(n), any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's already sorted by score, just iterate over it and get the best four for each id and you're done, with `O(n)` time complexity.

Here's how:

```
import itertools

new_lst = []
for _, g in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x['id']):
    new_lst.extend(sorted(g, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)[:4])
```

Not a real test:

```
>>> lst = [{ "id": "1", "score": "5" },
{ "id": "1", "score": "4" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "9" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "8" },
{ "id": "3", "score": "99" }, 
{ "id": "3", "score": "98" }]
>>> new_lst = []
>>> for _, g in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x['id']):
    new_lst.extend(sorted(g, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)[:4])

>>> new_lst
[{'id': '1', 'score': '5'}, {'id': '1', 'score': '4'}, {'id': '2', 'score': '9'}, {'id': '2', 'score': '8'}, {'id': '3', 'score': '99'}, {'id': '3', 'score': '98'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort your list by `id` and `score` which takes `0(n)` and group them by `id` attribute which also takes `0(n)`.

```
import itertools

lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (int(x['id']), int(x['score'])))
grouped = itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x['id'])

for x, y in grouped:
    print list(y)[:-4]
```